# adding pixels to only some divs

Tags: jquery, css

I have a game that I have been developing, and I needed help adding 55 pixels to all the objects. I figured it out using a class around them all with the following code:

```
$('div.outline *').css("width", "+=55px");
```

But I just realized that is going to mess it up because I have some divs at `margin-left: 0px;`

**The Question Is:**

How do I do I loop through all the divs in that class and than add 55px to the ones that are not at `margin-left: 0px;`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can't you use CSS for this ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend not using direct CSS.  Instead create some classes:

```
.margin-left-zero { left-margin: 0 };
```

then it's as simple as:

```
$('div.outline *:not(.margin-left-zero)').css("width", "+=55px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **[jQuery .filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function:

```
$( 'div.outline *' ).filter( function( i, e ) {
    return parseInt( $( e ).css( 'margin-left' ), 10 ) > 0;
} ).css( 'width', '+=55px' );
```